# How to generate a circular mountain?

Tags: modeling, add-on

This is how I tried to make a circular mountain terrain (low poly), but it didn't work out. It should also include some small ledges where huge statues can be placed. Can I generate it rather than manually inserting each one one at a time? (For example, ANT Landscape add-on, but I'm not sure how).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you ok with geo nodes? Also do you want the ledges to be a part of the mountains and be a bit nore organic or is it fine for them to look like cubes places on the mountains? One more thing, you wan it to be low poly right?

Comment: Hello, maybe sculpt it?

Comment: Something simple and low poly would do, and yes more organic is good instead of extra cubes glitched on the mountains. I don't really know anything about geometry nodes but I'll give it a shot and hopefully learn a lot from you.

Comment: Hello @moonboots, I tried sculpting it but it is very time consuming and it is not very precise.

Comment: you can also combine the pieces from you work with boolean for example and use sculpting to smooth out the borders

Answer (score 7):

You could begin with a *Cloth* simulation, create a plane for your cloth, subdivide it, give it a *Cloth* simulation, create a circle for your ground, extrude inwards, create its profile, give it a *Collision* simulation:

[image]

Play the simulation:

[image]

tweak the cloth parameters (particularly the mass), when you're good apply the *Cloth* modifier, sculpt a bit:

Comment: That's really brilliant, I never thought of it. I'll give it a try.

Comment: but couldn't you also do an ocean simulation, throw a meteor in it and then use that as a starting point...? and wouldn't this be more realistic because of size? :D

Comment: sure but a meteor could destroy the whole human race, I prefer a simple cloth   :(

Comment: wow cloth can do this feature!

Comment: @ManaTree You can use it for something else than clothes, his landscape was looking like a cloth  ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have created a geometry nodes setup.

(For beginnner: If you don't understand any part, just use the viewer node to see what changes each node has made)

[image]

First you take a grid. Keep the resolution of the grid to maintain the low poly look. We are going to change the Z-axis position of each point on this grid.

For that we take the circle. The number of vertices on this circle are equal to the number of mountains.

We then use the geometry proximity nodes to find the distance of the points from the grid points.(Make sure it is set to points)
We map this distance from "0 to 1" to "1 to 0".
Now we input this value in the z socket of the Commbine XYZ node.

Next we use a noise texture and multiply it with the height gradient we had created earlier.
We simply add this to the Combine XYZ node. The scale of the noise texture will influence the intensity of it. This noise has been mixed to add an organic look to the mountains.

We use this as an offset in the set position node to actually set the position of the geometry.
The RGB curves can be changed to change the slope of the mountains and make then a bit curvier if you want.

The mountains part is done.
[image]
I made the ledges as a seperate geo nodes modifier.

The ledges are just cubes instanced on this geometry.

We take the position, seperate the z component and put it into the Color Ramp factor. We select a range from this and to get a boolean output from this we use a compare node set to greater than. Secondly we use the length of the position and use a less than compare to sort of get radius effect kind of thing. We use a boolean math node set to And. We connect the Z-axis selection and this radius thingy. Simply put, it will output a yes if both the conditions are satisfied. We use this as a selection for the points to instance. So what will happen is only the points which are selected will be instanced upon.
[image]
[image]

The solution provided by moonboots will give you a beautiful landscapy look. But you will have to simulate it and also it's not going to be particularly low poly. You can use a decimate modifier and reduce the geometry though.

If you do want the ledges to not look like slapped on to the mountains I would suggest a remesh and decimate combination after. (Put a solidify after the first geo nodes modifier as remesh does not work with non-maniflod(planar) meshes). This will be a bit messy. But organic things do create a mess. So in a few cases low poly is sort of not possible.

Another thick would be to self model the cubes and use a few vertex bevels to give it the low-poly kind of organic look. (Maybe make a bunch of these and use them as a collection to input into the instances socket. Will give a bit of diversity)